# how to order the flexbox direction vertically?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'am using flexbox on a wrapper and i have 2 rows and 3 columns like this:

```
A B C
1 2 3
```

This is more or less the problem that i have:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="col col-1">
          <div class="title">
            <img src={"http://es.rockybytes.com/i/393/image.jpg"} />
          </div>
          <div class="content">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-2">
          <div class="title">
            <img
              src={
                "https://www.portalprogramas.com/imagenes/programas/es/704/6704_0.jpg"
              }
            />
          </div>
          <div class="content">2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-3">
          <div class="title">C</div>
          <div class="content">3</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

The letters A, B , C are images of different sizes. I'm fixing the width which makes the numbers cells (1 2 & 3) not being aligned.

For example if the height of C is half of the height of B, 3 will be closer to the top than 2.

I've solved this by creating two rows od 3 columns. So now everything is aligned on desktop. (the first row has the css:       `align-items: center;display:flex;` on it)

Row 1 : A B C with the images vertically centered
Row 2:  1 2  3: They are naturally starting from the top, here, as intended, aligned

The problem is that going to mobile I get

```
A
B
C
1
2
3
```

But I would love to have

```
A
1
B
2
C
3
```

Anyway to do this only with css?

I'm doing an app in react: It is possible to do it with some "isMobile" conditions and creating 2 different schemas. but would be awesome to be able to do it just configurating the css flexbox

SOLUTION:
I wasn't able to do it with two rows, I'v used one row and `align-items: baseline` instead as suggested by @subgeo

Comment: yet's i would be possible through nesting row and colum flex

Comment: You can use flex order. See https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Hey! i'm already using flex order but all them seems to order horizontally, where I want a vertical order (the one on the example, where we pick column by column)

Comment: do you have any image of what you've done so far?

Comment: I've updated the example. You can see my problem here also:
https://impakta-landing.firebaseapp.com/ 
Clicking on the tab "impacto"
You can see that the third column is not aligned with the rest. 

Solved it creating two rows so i can align A with B with C 
and 1 with 2 with 3.

However the mobile version, when i get only one column, i get the result row by row instead of column by column.


Note: the current state of the app is the non-aligned A-B-C code where the mobile version works as expected

Comment: In this website, I see the problem on desktop version (third column not aligned with the rest... easily fixable with `align-items: baseline;` on the container flex element) but not in the mobile. Why making 2 rows with 3 columns instead of 1 row with 3 columns and 2 blocks inside each column?

Comment: can you update your css. @LoïcV

Comment: in the website we only have the problem on desktop because there is only one row. My solution of having 2 rows is in local.

What I had in mind: I wanted the imagesto be aligned with the middle point of the biggest image (so the space between the first row and the second is variable but everything on the second row starts at the same heigth). Creating 2 rows let me do this by aligning on the center everything on row 1.

However, this is magic: `align-items: baseline;` not exactly what i was trying but it's a perfect solution :) i've lost a couple of hours playing with this! Thank you!

Comment: Nice to hear it worked for you! :D But, the easier thing you can do (in the 2 rows approach) I think is to duplicate content, so, you'll have the `.title` and `.content` elements in the column but you'll hide `.content` on desktop and `.row-2` on mobile with media queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your container as a flex with `flex-flow: row wrap`. Take a look at this example.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.col {
  width: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-right: 3px;
}

.col-1 {
  background-color: #f99;
}

.col-2 {
  background-color: #9f9;
}

.col-3 {
  background-color: #99f;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="col col-1">
        <div class="title">A</div>
        <div class="content">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-2">
        <div class="title">B</div>
        <div class="content">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-3">
        <div class="title">C</div>
        <div class="content">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well i just realized that my example is not enougth to solve my problem.  I'm editing the description. Sorry for that